# std::map unique std::less<> function for a 2D point as key

Tags: c++, stl, binary-tree, std

Well, after four hours of debugging, confused as I could be, I found out the cause of the problem...

I am making some program that saves some point in a std::map and render those in my window.
But weirdly, some points failed to make it into the map.

```
std::map<Point2, Prop*> m_Props_m;

void AddProp(std::pair<Point2, Prop*> p)
{
    m_Props_m.insert(p);
}

struct Point2
{
unsigned int Point2::x;
unsigned int Point2::y;
//--------
Point2::Point2()
    :x(0)
    ,y(0)
{}

bool Point2::operator< (const Point2& b) const
{
    return ( x+y < b.x+b.y );
}

bool Point2::operator> (const Point2& b) const
{
    return ( x+y > b.x+b.y );
}
};
```

Thank god I have some experience with binary trees so I could find out the cause of my problem.

Imagine we have 2 Point2's.

```
Point2 a(0,1);
Point2 b(1,0);
```

As you can see, with the operator< method I have written it would return false, and the operator> would also return false. Thus if a is already in the map, and b gets inserted, the insertion fails.

Now, this is all good and well, but how can I fix this? Is there any way I could have a less than operator for a 2D point that would allow me to store every unique point in the map?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::map` doesn't use `operator>` at all, so you don't have to worry about that.

To sort on multiple fields (in this case, two), use a so-called "lexicographical ordering", meaning that the first field is most important, and the second breaks ties:

```
bool operator<(const Point2 &lhs, const Point2 &rhs) {
    return (lhs.x < rhs.x) || ((lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y < rhs.y));
}
```

Comment: Well, it must use something in order to determine whether a key is 'smaller' or 'bigger' than some other key?

Comment: @xcrypt: it only uses `operator<` (well, actually `std::less<Point2>` is the default comparator, but assuming that isn't specialized it in turn uses `operator<`). The map treats two keys `x` and `y` as equal if `!(x<y) && !(y<x)`.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter for ints, in general I prefer: `lhs.x < rhs.x || !(rhs.x < lhs.x) && lhs.y < rhs.y`. It places fewer requirements on the types.

Comment: @Charles: fair point, I wrote it that way purely because IMO it most closely matches what I wrote in English ("the second breaks ties"). I added redundant parens to emphasise the priority of `&&` over `||` too. Optimizing for style and/or usefulness in generic code are left as exercise for the reader. Another option is `return std::make_pair(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::make_pair(rhs.x, rhs.y);`, although I suppose that's also risky in generic code since it might expensively copy the members.

Comment: @Steve: The last point would be solved with `std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y)` (or boost equivalent).

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison function considers points equivalent if the sum of their coordinates is equal. For example, (2, 5) is equivalent to (3, 4), because 2 + 5 = 3 + 4. Points that already have their equivalent in the map won't make it.

A better idea would be to compare by x first, and by y second if x value is equal in both points.

```
bool operator< (const Point2 &lhs, const Point2 &rhs) {
    return (lhs.x < rhs.x) || ((lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y < rhs.y));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
bool Point2::operator< (const Point2& b) const
{
    if (x<b.x) return true;
    else if (!(b.x<x) && y<b.y) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

`std::map` only uses `operator<`. If `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`, `a` and `b` are equivalent (not the same as equal), and thus the map will only store one of them. `operator>` is not used.

It might not make sense for comparing Point2's in other cases, so to avoid misunderstandings, I'd suggest that you provide a compare-function for your map, and remove the `operator<` from your class.

```
bool mapLessPoint2(const Point2& a, const Point2& b);
std::map<Point2, Prop*, &mapLessPoint2> m_Props_m;
```

In my opinion operator overloading should only be used when it makes sense for the given type, and that one point in a 2D space is larger than another point in a 2D space is not intuitive.